# Best practices to load and display a list of images in an hybrid app

Tags: performance, ionic-framework, lazy-loading, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a Ionic-1 app in which there's a large list that displays images (I use `collection-repeat` for this).

For now, I ship the images with the app. But the list evolves with time so my app gets the list from a server, then checks if there are new items, and use remote urls for new images.

The list is getting bigger (more tha 300 items), so managing this is quite heavy on the app. Moreover, shipping the images with the app is going to become impossible, because the .apk or .ipa are getting too big.

So I would like to use a better way to manage my images and also a better way to display them dynamically.

Is that possible to call the server images in my collection-repeat and to make it smooth and performant? Is that possible, that once an image has been called, it's saved in the local memory (maybe localStorage) so that the next time the list displayed it's faster ? If yes, how to do this ?

Is that the best way to manage a dynamical list? I would like to hear the best practice for this, for the best UX.

Here's my bit of code:

```
<div class="boardselection firstScreen" ng-if="transitionFinished">

<ion-item collection-repeat="item in prodataSelect | orderBy:data.sort | filter: data.selectBrand.brand:true | filter: data.selectName.name | filter: generalSearchFunc | filterObj:['brand','modelStrict']" item-width="25%" item-height="35%" item-render-buffer="16">

    <a class="optionfuninit item-content" data-proid="{{item.id}}" on-tap="whatToDo(item.id,$event);" ng-class="item.fun == '0' ? 'aNormal' :( item.fun == '1' ? 'aSmallWave' : (item.fun == '2' ? 'aStepUp' : ''))">

        <div class="listviewTrophy" ng-if="isWinning(item.id)">
            <i class="icon ion-trophy"></i>
        </div>
        <i class="icon ion-female" ng-show="item.gender == 'female'"></i>
        <!-- <p class="flex-caption" fittext fittext-min="10" fittext-max="15" ng-bind="item.modelStrict" > 
            {{item.modelStrict}}
        </p> -->
        <div class="listviewtexts flex-caption" ng-class="item.fun == '0' ? 'aNormal' :( item.fun == '1' ? 'aSmallWave' : (item.fun == '2' ? 'aStepUp' : ''))">
            <span class="listviewtextsmodel">{{item.modelStrict}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="imagebox">
            <img class="imageoptionsmodel " ng-src="{{imagesUrls[item.imageName]}}"/>
        </div>

    </a>

</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **ionic-cache-src** (https://github.com/BenBBear/ionic-cache-src)

it will work like :
[image]

**or**

you can use **$ImageCacheFactory** to save it in cache,
docs [here](http://mcgivery.com/preload-images-ionic/).

Comment: Wow super nice ! What's the best choice between the two ? What would you recommend for my case (a big grid list with collection-repeat)? Thanks!

Comment: And ionic-cache-src doesn't seem to have been maintained recently, does it ?